# Getting an array from one to many relationship in Laravel using a custom key

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, relationship

I'm learning Laravel right now and I'm stumped on how to get an array of records from one table that belong to a record on another table based on a key.

I have two tables:

```
titles
-------------------
id | title_name | created_at | updated_at

posts
-------------------
id | titles_id | content
```

I have the route /{title_name} being controlled by the read() method on my PagesController.php

```
public function read($title){

    $title_name = $title;
    $title_id = Title::find($title)->id;
    $posts = Title::find($title)->posts;

    return view('pages/read')->with([
        'title_name' => $title_name,
        'title_id' => $title_id,
        'posts' => $posts
    ]);
}
```

But this doesn't seem to output anything. I have my models setup like this:

Title.php

```
class Title extends Model
{
     // Table Name
     protected $table = "titles";
     // Primary Key
     protected $primaryKey = "title";
     // Timestamps
     public $timestamps = "true";
     // Custom primaryKey
     public $incrementing = false;
     //relationship
     public function posts(){
          return $this->hasMany('App\Post', 'titles_id')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
     }
}
```

Post.php

```
class Post extends Model
{
     // Table Name
     protected $table = "posts";
     // Primary Key
     protected $primaryKey = "id";
     // Timestamps
     public $timestamps = "true";
     //relationship
     public function titles(){
          return $this->belongsTo('App\Title');
     }
}
```

I think the problem is that when I do Title::find($title)->post, laravel is trying to find posts where the titles_id = title_name, because I set title_name as the primaryKey, but I need it to be looking for the id column in the Titles table, and not the name...

Comment: you can use Title::where('id',$yourIdWhichWant)->post;

Comment: What doesn't it output? Do you have a white screen or are the posts not displayed.

Comment: Thanks Th3 I'll try than and let you guys know how it goes. @Jan it just isn't displaying the posts

Comment: So I tried that and I'm getting this error:  (1/1) ErrorException
Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::$posts

Answer (score 1):

Alright I will give you an example where I explain everything you do wrong.

Tables:

```
titles
-------------------
id | title_name | created_at | updated_at

posts
-------------------
id | title_id | content
```

Not `titles_id` but `title_id`, eloquent likes this more.

Your controller:

```
public function read($titleName){
    // The first function argument is the name of the title,
    // not the title model.
    // Also don't use snake_case in laravel(Except helpers) but camelCase.
    // We are not going to use find, you might have set the name as 
    // primary key, but the id column still exists.
    // firstOrFail() means get the first result, if there isn't, throw
    // a model not found exception(404).
    $title = Title::where('name', $titleName)->firstOrFail();

    return view('pages/read')->with([
        // You could just do 'title' => $title, and do the rest in the view.
        'title_name' => $title->name,
        'title_id' => $title->id,
        'posts' => $title->posts
    ]);
}
```

Title model:

```
class Title extends Model
{
     // $table not needed, laravel knows this(Yes pure magic).

     // No, we don't want name as primary key.

     // Timestamps is true by default, so we don't need it.

     public function posts(){
          return $this->hasMany(\App\Post::class)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
     }
}
```

Post model:

```
class Post extends Model
{
     // This function should be called title, not titles.
     public function title(){
          return $this->belongsTo(App\Title::class);
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth response, I'll try this out and report back!